# Is Microsoft.ajax.js necessary for ASP.NET MVC ajax stuff?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

It it necessary to include microsoft.ajax javascript files to use code such as:

```
@Ajax.BeginForm()
```

Comment: Why not just take it out and see if it works?

Comment: @SpikeX sometimes things seem to work while breaking in subtle ways, so I wouldn't generally recommend (exclusively) "see if it works"

Comment: Well at the very least you could rule out a reference/library compile-time error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's no longer necessary. ASP.NET MVC 3 uses jquery by default. So you need `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` which ajaxifies the HTML5 data-* attributes generated by the `Ajax.*` helpers. So no more `MicrosoftAjax*.js`.

Comment: BTW. are you part of the mvc team? You answer ALOT of mvc questions.

Comment: @Lol coder, no I am not part of the MVC team. I am part of the beer amateurs team :-)

Comment: @Lol coder, if this answer helped you solve the problem you were having please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: was waiting on the timer thing, I always mark my answers if they helped. I have probably like 20 answers marked for u lol.